# How do simple data normalization in clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I have this vector of maps:

```
(def db 
 [{:id "foo" :content "foo-content" :tags []}
  {:id "bar" :content "bar-content" :tags []}
  {:id "baz etc" :content "baz-content" :tags []}])
```

I want to transform it to get a map of maps with direct access to values by ids, like this:

```
{:foo {:content "foo-content" :tags []}
 :bar {:content "bar-content" :tags []}
 :baz-etc {:content "baz-content" :tags []}
```

This is my attempt:

```
(defn normalize [db]
  (into {}
    (for [item db]
      [(:id item) (dissoc item :id)])))
```

How to do better (key conversions? more stuff to think of?)?

Is there a library I can use?

Thanks!

Comment: I think what you have is good. Despite its general-sounding name ‘normalize’ that function does a specific data transformation that surely deserves three lines of code …?

Comment: datascript will also build such indices (which is what you're doing) for arbitrary attributes so you can easily access them. Might be worth a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert string to keyword with `keyword` function.

```
(defn normalize [db]
   (into {}
     (for [item db]
       [(keyword (:id item)) (dissoc item :id)])))
```

You can also use `clojure.walk/keywordize-keys`.

```
(defn normalize [db]
  (clojure.walk/keywordize-keys
   (into {}
     (for [item db]
       [(:id item) (dissoc item :id)]))))
```

But there is a problem. `"baz etc"` will be converted `:baz etc`. So you have to replace space to `-` before apply `keyword` function  to id string.

And as @amalloy mentioned, convert string from a file/database to keyword is not a good idea. Those should be remained as strings.

Anyway, if you really need to convert strings to keywords, you can use the above methods.

Comment: I strongly discourage doing either of these things. If your input is strings from a file or a database or whatever, they should absolutely stay as strings. Keywords are for things you typed into the source code and know at compile time, mostly.